# How to use ssl certificate in a Next.js app?

Tags: ssl, next.js

I installed certificate like this:

```
# Install mkcert
brew install mkcert
mkcert -install
mkcert localhost
```

Files exist:

```
janoskukoda@Janoss-MacBook-Pro tikex-portal % ls -l *.pem
-rw-------  1 janoskukoda  staff  1708 Aug 13 19:37 localhost-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 janoskukoda  staff  1610 Aug 13 19:37 localhost.pem
```

Tried run app like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev -p 3000 --HTTPS=true --SSL_CRT_FILE=./localhost.pem --SSL_KEY_FILE=./localhost-key.pem"
}
```

without success. Chrome does not load anything on https.